# Can an invitation box be added to our site?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed

The Private Beta site for the DronesSE had this invitation box on the side:

[image]

I don't yet see it for our site. Is it possible for us to get this added too?

Comment: Hi @JNat, thank you! Did it turn out to be as simple as Glorfindel's suggestion to wait 24 hours, or did it have to be manually added?

Comment: It solved itself, as Glorfindel suggests :)

Comment: Thank you JNat!

Answer (score 6):

It's there now, probably a caching thing. I've seen other private betas on Stack Exchange where some functionality wasn't available until about 24 hours after launch.

[image]